# Ajax in Dojo with Perl

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl, post, dojo

Anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong?
I am creating a simple system to get people in and out of user groups and for that purpose I am using Dojo and Perl. (If I could have it my way it would be PHP but I am not the boss.)

At the moment I only use three files, one for Perl, one for JavaScript and one for CSS styles.

The start of the CGI script routes to different functions as follows:

```
if ($search = $cgi->param('psearch')) {
  dbConnect();
  jsonSearchPersons($search);
  dbDisconnect();
} elsif ($user_id = $cgi->param('person')){
  dbConnect();  
  create_form($user_id);
 dbDisconnect();
} elsif ($user_id = $cgi->param('saveuser')) {
  save_user();
} else {
  mainPage();
};
...
sub save_user {
  print $cgi->header(-type=>'text/plain',-charset=>'utf-8');
  print("success");
}
```

The problem I have now is when I want to save the new groups for the user though an Ajax call (a call to this URL: `users.cgi?saveuser=xx`). This should (in my point of view) be a POST call, so I made this and tried to append the resulting HTML/text in a `<div>` but it didn't work:

```
dojo.xhr.post({
  url: "/cgi-bin/users.cgi?saveuser="+user_id,
  content: {
    new_groups: group_ids.toString()
  },
  load: function(html_content){
    var element = document.getElementById("test_area");
    element.innerHTML = html_content;
  },
  error: function(){
    alert("An error has occured during the save of new user groups.");
  }
});
```

When I do it with `dojo.xhr.get();` it works fine, but when I do it with the **POST** it's like it jumps over that part of the if statement and just appends the `mainPage()` function. Is there something basic I don't understand between Dojo and Perl? Do I have to set up the pages so it will accept a POST call? Or what am I doing wrong?

NOTE: This is the first "system" I have made though Dojo and Perl. (I'm normally a PHP/jQuery kind of guy who makes everything UI by hand, so I'm kinda new to it.)

Comment: GET uses $ENV{QUERY_STRING}, POST reads STDIN.   Does dojo do anything weird like set the query string for posts ?   You could debug this by printing out %ENV and checking for QUERY_STRING and CONTENT_LENGTH. for GET, QUERY_STRING should be set, and CONTENT_LENGTH=0. For POST, QUERY_STRING should by '', and CONTENT_LENGTH should be > 0

Comment: This I didn't know. Im gonna try it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the `saveuser`-parameter to the `content`-object of `dojo.xhrPost` instead of passing it in the url.

You're trying to pass the saveuser-parameter as GET and the other as POST, maybe that confuses your serverside part.

Try it like that:

```
dojo.xhr.post({
  url: "/cgi-bin/users.cgi",
  content: {
   new_groups: group_ids.toString(),
   saveuser: user_id
  },
  load: function(html_content){
    var element = document.getElementById("test_area");
    element.innerHTML = html_content;
  },
  error: function(){
    alert("An error has occured during the save of new user groups.");
  }
 });
```

Comment: Yeah that might work. But is it not possible to post to an url like users.cgi?some=xx ?(i know you can in jquery) Should it not be a server side problem? But then again, i can connect to the site through a browser an see the success message.

Comment: I'm not into perl at all, it's just a wild guess: Maybe it does not respect GET-data if there are also POST-data ...

Comment: You where right Michael. Perl don't like when you mix GET and POST since it uses the same class/module to get the variables. So if you fetch for a variable like "saveuser" you fetch for both the GET and POST representation. If that makes sence.

Answer (score 0):

Line 675 of CGI.pm :

```
  # Some people want to have their cake and eat it too!
  # Uncomment this line to have the contents of the query string
  # APPENDED to the POST data.
  # $query_string .= (length($query_string) ? '&' : '') . $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'} if defined $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
```

Made me laugh !

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

The problem was my javascript. When posting to a perl script you use $cgi=new CGI; and all that. This takes both GET and POST variables and validates them. In my javascript/dojo code, i then used an url with GET vars and then made a POST as well. This meant perl could not find out (or was mixing) the two variable types. So when i changed my ajax code (as below) it worked, since $cgi->param('saveuser') both fetches GET and POST of "saveuser" (no change to the perl was needed):

```
dojo.xhr.post({
  url: "/cgi-bin/users.cgi",
  content: {
    saveuser: user_id,
    new_groups: group_ids.toString()
  },
  load: function(html_content){
    var element = document.getElementById("test_area");
    element.innerHTML = html_content;
  },
  error: function(){
    alert("An error has occured during the save of new user groups.");
  }
});
```

Kinda wack bug, but im glad since it works great now :D